# Расположение элементов в FlowLayout

Tags: android, xml

Есть данный элемент экрана. Теги расположены в контейнере `FlowLayout`(сторонняя библиотека), который автоматически переносит элементы на другую строку, если они не вмещаются. Проблема заключается в том, что мне нужно отображать только 1 строку тегов, а по нажатию на "еще" отображать остальные. Может есть у кого-нибудь идеи как решить данную проблему.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Методы создания тегов

```
 private void createTag(Context context, FlowLayout container, TagEntity tagEntity){

    TextView txt = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.tag_view, null);

    String tagText=tagEntity.getName();
    if (tagText.length()>9){
        txt.setText(tagText.substring(0,9)+"...");
    }
    else{
        txt.setText(tagEntity.getName());
    }
    txt.setBackgroundResource(tagEntity.getTagGroup().getColor());
    FlowLayout.LayoutParams fl =new FlowLayout.LayoutParams(FlowLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            FlowLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );

    fl.setMargins(16,16,16,16);
    container.addView(txt,fl);
}


private void createTagFromList(Context context,FlowLayout container,List<TagEntity> list){
    for (TagEntity tagEntity :list){
        createTag(context,container, tagEntity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вы сами не нашли способа - то хотя бы приведите ссылку на либу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что если элементу задать фиксированную высоту, а при нажатии на кнопку "ещё" добавлять нужное количество dp (менять высоту)?

P.S.
На всякий случай, чтобы перевести высоту из dp в int для программного использования, можно вызвать метод

```
int valueInPixels = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.yourValueInDp);
```